# Difference in sha512sum in Ubuntu and online tools

Tags: hash, sha512

I created a text file in Ubuntu called text.txt with some text and no newline at the end.
When I use online sha512 hash generators, I get different results than sha512sum.  Why is that?

```
    # echo "8====D" > test.txt  
    # sha512sum test.txt
```

549f38836f34b6fe2ca8661f5bd91dfcbcb2e675c338e7eb50390f8ebb509f28fb6df9ebcb0493cfa661b042180a9b351f6c06dbd628300e47cbdf4d13e6d9b2  test2.txt

http://passwordsgenerator.net/sha512-hash-generator/ and http://hash.online-convert.com/sha512-generator show the hash as: ba54cdfcc32c0789acd1ee74ccd7cf2e5140f58b3d6864620c24793a93f01253d040bb3264a17629f1f0448eb22f600c6c1e5274162db97b913bde30ff16c6eb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

echo implicitly adds a "\n" newline character. If you omit that, the output is the same as that from the mentioned online tools:

```
$ echo -n "8====D" | sha512sum
ba54cdfcc32c0789acd1ee74ccd7cf2e5140f58b3d6864620c24793a93f01253d040bb3264a17629f1f0448eb22f600c6c1e5274162db97b913bde30ff16c6eb
```

Comment: Thanks!  I guess vi does the same thing, because that's what I was using before trying echo.